# Conditionally transform column in spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark

Suppose I have a dataframe such as the following:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.{Row, DataFrame, SparkSession}
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.{StructType, StructField, IntegerType, StringType, DoubleType, NumericType}
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.{udf, col, skewness}

val someData = Seq(
  Row(8, "bat"),
  Row(64, "mouse"),
  Row(-27, "horse"),
  Row(null, "mouse"),
  Row(27, null)
)

val someSchema = List(
  StructField("number", IntegerType, true),
  StructField("word", StringType, true)
)

val someDF = spark.createDataFrame(
  spark.sparkContext.parallelize(someData),
  StructType(someSchema)
)

val df = someDF.withColumn("constantColumn", lit(1))
```

I would like to calculate the skewness of each column having a NumericType-like type. Then, if a column's skewness is above a certain threshold, I would like to transform it via `f(x) = log(x + 1)`. (I know that performing log-transforms on negative data will give a NaN, but I would like to eventually write code that will take this possibility into account).

**What I have tried so far:**

I have found a way to do it, but it requires a mutable dataframe `df`. From my limited understanding, this is not desirable.

```
val log1p = scala.math.log1p(_)
val log1pUDF = udf(scala.math.log1p(_: Double))
val transformThreshold = 0.04

// filter those columns which have a type that inherits from NumericType
val numericColumns = df.columns.filter(column => df.select(column).schema(0).dataType.isInstanceOf[NumericType])

// for columns having NumericType, filter those that are sufficiently skewed
val columnsToTransform = numericColumns.filter(numericColumn => df.select(skewness(df(numericColumn))).head.getDouble(0) > transformThreshold)

// for all columns that are sufficiently skewed, perform log1p transform and add it to df 
for(column <- columnsToTransform) {

   // df should be mutable here!
   df = df.withColumn(column + "_log1p", log1pUDF(df(column))) 
}
```

**My questions:**

- How can I achieve the goal without using mutable dataframes?
- Is there an easier/quicker way to achieve what I have tried to do?

(Run on Spark 2.4.0, Scala 2.11.12.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of `for()` structure, you could use a recursive function :

```
def rec(df: DataFrame, columns: List[String]): DataFrame = columns match {
  case Nil => df
  case h :: xs => rec(df.withColumn(s"${h}_log1p", log1pUDF(col(h))), xs)
}
```

Comment: Nice one! Your answer made me realize I can also use a foldLeft to achieve this goal: `columnsToTransform.foldLeft(df)((myDF, col) => myDF.withColumn(col + "_log1p", log1pUDF(myDF(col))))`